# Mount a hard drive with dual boot on it

Tags: dual-boot, mount, external-hdd

My old hard drive has a dual boot system of Windows 7 and Ubuntu 16.04 on it. Before my old computer crashed I could not back up the data on it.

Now I want to get the data back, at least from the Ubuntu partition. The thing is when I plug in the old hard drive it is not being shown in the list of partitions in Nautilus.

`disks` however recognises a Hard Disk plugged in via USB but says it's "500GB Unkown" with device name `/dev/sdb`.

How can I normally mount the disk from within Ubuntu?

Outputs:

1. `vgscan` (as suggested in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/550409/how-to-read-mount-full-ubuntu-volume-from-now-external-hard-drive)):

   ```
   Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
   ```
2. `lsblk -f /dev/sdb`:

   ```
   NAME FSTYPE LABEL UUID MOUNTPOINT
   sdb
   ```
3. `fdisk -l /dev/sdbfdisk -l /dev/sdb`

   ```
   Disk /dev/sdb: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   ```

Comment: Your linked answer isn't applicable unless you had full disk encryption. The disk is most likely damaged.

Comment: What's the output of `sudo lsblk -f /dev/sdb`? Replace `/dev/sdb` with whatever path the device happens to have after you connect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you *lost* your partitions. You can try to recover your lost partitions if no more actions have been done to the disk *(format, write...)*.

Boot from your new Ubuntu install on that machine, open a terminal and install `testdisk` with `sudo apt install testdisk`.

Then run `sudo testdisk` and follow the on screen *menu-like* instructions, to try to recover your partitions with this tool.

If you still can't recover them or want to see more options, check [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery#Lost_Partition) about partition recovery from Ubuntu wiki.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, the partitions seems lost. `testdisk` could not find any partitions while `gpart` only sees read errors :/ I am giving the disk to experts now.