# How to access an LVM partition on an external USB disk?

Tags: partitioning, mount, disk, lvm

I have a external USB disk that is format using LVM. There are 2 logical partitions inside the LVM partition. When I plug it I can see the disk with GParted, but the disk partitions are not shown in the file manager. Nor is the command to mount the partitions enabled in GParted.

How can I mount the 2 partitions and access them from Ubuntu 17.04?

Comment: Can you see the partitions in Disks? you might be able to mount them from there, click the partition then on the little arrowhead to mount.

Comment: You might also look at [https://askubuntu.com/questions/550409/how-to-read-mount-full-ubuntu-volume-from-now-external-hard-drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/550409/how-to-read-mount-full-ubuntu-volume-from-now-external-hard-drive), under the assumption that you do not have encryption on this drive.