# Recovering system after deleting old files in /boot

Tags: boot, kernel, data-recovery, recovery-mode

Some days ago I ruined my Ubuntu server (Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 LTS) when deleting some files in my boot-directory.
It seemed that system-updates had completed to version 4.4.0-93 so I removed all versions with versionnumber below 4.4.0-90
On reboot `/vlinuz-4.4.0-89-generic` is missing.
Alternative boot wint versions 4.4.0-87 and 4.4.0-85 also failed and the use of recovery-boot too.

I don't know why the system is asking for former versions of the system but I decided to try to recover the deleted files with an live-version of Knoppix 7.7.

Running Testdisk however all the files that I deleted seemed to have a size of 0 bytes (after deleting the files in the boot directory, the reboot did not start, so I cannot explain the files being overwritten).

**My current file listing of `/boot`**

```
total 101394
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1246835 Aug 10 07:02 abi-4.4.0-92-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1247269 Aug 11 19:40 abi-4.4.0-93-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   190356 Aug 10 07:02 config-4.4.0-92-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   190356 Aug 11 19:40 config-4.4.0-93-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root     1024 Aug  4 00:21 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 35445421 Aug  2 02:47 initrd.img-4.4.0-87-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 35452773 Aug  4 00:21 initrd.img-4.4.0-89-generic
drwx------ 2 root root    12288 Jan 10  2015 lost+found
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   182704 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   184380 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   184840 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw------- 1 root root  3884798 Aug 10 07:02 System.map-4.4.0-92-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  3885811 Aug 11 19:40 System.map-4.4.0-93-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  7097936 Aug  8 09:58 vmlinuz-4.4.0-91-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  7098032 Aug 10 07:02 vmlinuz-4.4.0-92-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  7097296 Aug 11 19:40 vmlinuz-4.4.0-93-generic
```

Can anyone help me to get the system running again or is the best way a fresh install of Ubuntu and all the applications and configuration-files?

Is it possible to reinstall the system from an alternative boot with Knoppix live-CD?

It would take me a few days and if there is a good way to do it faster (and safe) this would be preferred.

=== after trying suggestion from bodhi.zazen ===========

Thanks for replying,
unfortunately mount `/dev/sda` did not work
see below my results from the Knoppix terminal

> ```
>     knoppix@Microknoppix:~$ sudo fdisk -l Disk /dev/ram0: 4 MiB, 4194304
>     bytes, 8192 sectors
>     Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>     Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
>     I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>
>
>     Disk /dev/ram1: 4 MiB, 4194304 bytes, 8192 sectors
>     Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>     Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
>     I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>
>          ========= some other ==============
>
>     Disk /dev/sda: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors 
>     Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes 
>     Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
>     I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>     Disklabel type: dos Disk identifier: 0x000868f0
>
>      Device     Boot  Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type 
>      /dev/sda1  *      2048     499711     497664  243M 83 Linux 
>      /dev/sda2       501758 3907028991 3906527234  1.8T  5 Extended 
>      /dev/sda5       501760 3907028991 3906527232  1.8T 8e Linux LVM
>
>
>      root@Microknoppix:~# sudo mount /dev/sda /mnt mount: /dev/sda is
>      write-protected, mounting read-only mount: wrong fs type, bad option,
>      bad superblock on /dev/sda,
>      missing codepage or helper program, or other error
>
>    In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
>    dmesg | tail or so.
> ```

`/dev/sda` seems to be my root level, but is not accessible

`/dev/sda1` is mounted as my boot sector (in Knoppix it points to the directory that contains all the files of my boot sector on hard disk),

`/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sda5` are not accessible.

Comment: too tired for me to give real advice...  but I'd expect a re-install to NOT kill my config files (even if I did re-install software).  I'd backup your config anyway (you only spoke of a wiped /boot! -- did you apt-get autoremove etc to wipe them cleanly or just `rm`?) then re-install OS at worst.  I know I've grabbed /boot files from another like system and had it running well enough I could 'upgrade' it to latest kernel (I copied an old kernel so it'd update on the sick-box).  I'd assume it'd work for  shrinkfs (ubuntu) install images too, but haven't tried sorry.

Comment: Since Knoppix can build a 16.04 LTS live-CD, you willl be able to reinstall your system. After doing a backup of your files, it's better you to redo a system install, due to crash level you have got after that.

Comment: If you give up and decide to reinstall, I'd suggest you have a look at apt-clone to reinstall the same packages and maybe copy your home folder for most of the configs.

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to boot Ubuntu? What do you see on the screen?

Comment: from the knoppix mount your server in a chroot and reinstall the kernels. Make sure to mount /boot in the chroot if you have a separate boot partition. See - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot (you use your server / and /boot as a chroot, do not create a chroot, skip to setup with /proc and resolvconf). Then you can chroot in and `sudo apt-get --reinstall kernel_name`

Comment: You are using LVM, you need to access your LVM from knoppix. As far as I know Knoppix does not support LVM, so use an Ubuntu live media instead. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/550409/how-to-read-mount-full-ubuntu-volume-from-now-external-hard-drive and http://www.linuxwave.info/2007/11/mounting-lvm-disk-using-ubuntu-livecd.html . Again I do not know the names of your LVM volumes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not write all the details as I do not know your partitions.

You should be able to reinstall kernels, and other packages, from the knoppix live media via chroot.

Obtain a root shell as we are running these commands as root

```
sudo -i
```

Now mount your server root partition and if you have a separate /boot at /mnt

```
sudo mount /dev/your_root /mnt
sudo mount /dev/your/boot /mnt/boot #this may not be necessary
```

Setup chroot

```
mount -o bind /proc /mnt/proc
cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf
```

chroot and reinstall kernels

```
chroot /mnt
apt-get --reinstall linux-image-version_here
```

exit chroot and reboot

Comment: For LVM see https://askubuntu.com/questions/550409/how-to-read-mount-full-ubuntu-volume-from-now-external-hard-drive